# EXCEL Look up max number (possible multiple results) and return another column same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
A  B  
1  Pilot1
3  Pilot2    
4  Pilot3    
6  Pilot4    
15 Pilot5    
10 Pilot6    
3  Pilot7    
8  Pilot8
15 Pilot9
```

What is the excel formula for looking up the highest value(s) in column A and returning the Pilot(s) name(s).

I am using right now:

`=MAX(A1:A9)` to return the max number cuz I need that info too.

And

`=VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A9), A1:B9, 2, FALSE)`

and this give me the answer if there is on max or the first it comes to for multiple maxes.

So I would get with this:

```
15    
Pilot5
```

It does not give me

```
15    
15    
Pilot5    
Pilot9
```

I want the results to show:

```
15  -  for the max # of flights done
Pilot5
Pilot9 - for the names of the pilots that have the max flight count
```

Comment: =FILTER(A1:B9, A1:A9=max(A1:A9)) works great in google sheets

Answer (score 0):

So I noted above a more elegant way to do this in Google Sheets. And there are some very obscure ways out there, but here is something simple. The downside is it does show some extra information. Let us say your data is in A1:B9 and in A10 you have `=MAX(A1:A9)` [this is not strictly needed, but like you said, you want it anyway -- and it makes the formula a little less ugly]
Then in C1 put the formula `=if(A1=A$10,B1,"")` which will be blank if the pilot is not the max and have the pilot name otherwise. Drag that formula down through C9. Now in C10 (or wherever) put `=TEXTJOIN(", ",true,C1:C9)`
which will put together your pilot(s) separated by comma and space, and with blank entries omitted.

Comment: Awesome,  thats exactly what I need, and then I can just die the C column and put that final info in my stats column.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I had not thought of hiding the column. Nice touch. Feel free to accept the answer if you have a moment.